# InvocationTargetException при открытии файла

Tags: android, файлы, kotlin

Есть код, который читает CSV файл:

```
if (csvFile.exists() && csvFile.canRead()) {
      FileInputStream(csvFile.absoluteFile).use { stream ->
      return stream
   }
}
```

Возникает ошибка:

> Process: com.mobile_solutions.mycar, PID: 26602
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:558)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mobile_solutions.mycar/files/CarModels.csv:
> open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
> at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:574)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:160)
> at
> com.mobile_solutions.mycar.static.Functions.getCsvInputStream(Functions.kt:248)
> at
> com.mobile_solutions.mycar.ui.newDesign.addCar.brand.AddCarBrandViewModel.fillCarBrands(AddCarBrandViewModel.kt:32)
> at
> com.mobile_solutions.mycar.ui.newDesign.addCar.brand.AddCarBrandFragment.onViewCreated(AddCarBrandFragment.kt:66)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1823)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:547)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
> Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a
> directory)
> at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:564)

Файл, абсолютноточно точно, не директория. Но в ошибке присутствует:

> Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a
> directory)

Почему так и что делать?

Comment: Ему видней - если говорит директория, значит директория. Как, когда и кем создан этот файл? Проверьте правильно ли это сделано. Проверьте сам файл на момент вызова этого кода, если он создаётся вашим приложением

Comment: @woesss гружу его из firebase

Comment: Удачно грузите, ошибок нет в логах? Через проводник пощупайте что вы там нагрузили.

Comment: логи приложил в вопрос @woesss

Comment: Это лог попытки чтения, а я про запись спрашивал. Нет, ну если вы не заинтересованы в решении проблемы, то я умываю руки - по предоставленной вами информации советовать больше нечего.